# Can't play video from raw folder using dynamic path

Tags: android, html, android-videoview

i have a strange behavior while coding a video player. I have an html5 menu that targets mp4 videos. When you click on a video, the path will be treated and a native video player intent will start to play the video. My videos are placed in "raw" folder.

When I use a static path, the video plays very well:

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1;
```

When I use the following path, I can't play it:

```
video_title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("video_title");

String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + "R.raw."+video_title;
```

Note that i removed the extension of the file in the main intent so the variable "video_title" will hold the video title without extension.

Comment: did Your get an error or ist the video just not playing?

Comment: I'm getting "can't play this video"

Comment: Make a Log and check both uriPath strings, then You could see the difference. Maybe You get a wrong result for Your video_title-String.

Comment: I used the log and the variable "video_title" is good.

 android.resource://com.erc.swf_player/R.raw.video1

Comment: So sorry for those questions but without the relevant code, I couldn´t see any error. If Your video_title returning this full path: android.resource://com.erc.swf_player/R.raw.video1, then You doubled Your path. If this is the mistake, Your uriPath looks like this:  android.resource://com.erc.swf_player/R.raw. android.resource://com.erc.swf_player/R.raw.video1 . Just check the output String uriPath.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i resolved it, you can check the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue, by changing the uriPath variable:

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + "R.raw."+video_title; // BAD

String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + "raw/"+video_title; // GOOD
```